Custom schema validation rules with JsonValidator - executing only if the value matches the schema
I'm trying to implement a custom JsonValidator class which adds more validations on top of what should already be handled by the default validator based on the schema. Particularly, I wouldn't like to check myself whether the value being validated matches the schema before executing the additional checks, which assume it does.
I'd like the Validate() method being called after the default validation and having an easy way to check whether that validation passed. Or maybe having an option to suppress the call to the custom validator for values that don't match the schema.
I didn't find anything in the JsonValidatorContext object that helps with this.
Following the advice in this post I re-parsed the schema (to get rid of custom validators) and used it to check whether the value matches the schema before executing my custom validations.
public override void Validate(JToken value, JsonValidatorContext context)
{
    var defaultSchema = JSchema.Parse(context.Schema.ToString());
    if (value.IsValid(defaultSchema))
    {
        ValidateInternal(value, context);
    }
}

Is there a better way?

You can use an allOf operator to compose a custom validation rule with standard rules, however it seems Json.NET's implementation of allOf does not short-circuit and the custom rule is checked even after the preceding standard rule failed, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/5acq4i.  Despite that, does that answer your question sufficiently?

@dbc, thank you for putting this example together. I actually tried something similar. But as the schema became more complex, I needed to add more code to Validate() method to gracefully handle JSON that does not match the basic schema. For example, I needed to deal with situations when the JSON doesn't have the properties I expected or they were of wrong types - all that before getting to the custom checks.
What I was looking for is the efficient replacement to the short-circuit logic, which as you mentioned looks missing in Json.NET Schema implementation.

Why don't you use context.Schema directly ?
It skips re-parsing but still validates against the original schema.
And you won't even need to convert into the string
public override void Validate(JToken value, JsonValidatorContext context)
{
    if (value.IsValid(context.Schema))
    {
        ValidateInternal(value, context);
    }
}


Because that Schema object has custom validators, including the current one. So this code causes infinite recursion.
Maybe if I could pass context to that call, I could skip processing when the same validator is invoked. See my other question here
